# getting err in file sharing system using nodejs,express mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**This is my nodejs code**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

function connectDB() {
  //Database connection
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: true
  });

  const connection = mongoose.connection;


  connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Database connected.');
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('Connection failed.');
  })
}

module.exports = connectDB;
```

**Showing this err while I am trying to connect with server**

```
}).catch(err => {
            ^

TypeError: connection.once(...).catch is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

That means the `once` function does not return a promise object in the first place.

You can use `catch` with `mongoose.connect` to handle errors if there is any, check the example below:

```
function connectDB() {
    //Database connection
    mongoose.connect(
        process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_URL,
        {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: true
        }
    ).catch(err => console.log(err.reason));;

    const connection = mongoose.connection;

    connection.once('open', () => {
        console.log('Database connected.');
    })
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Does it return a promise?

```
db.once('open', function(err, resp){
  console.log(resp);
});
```

Or

```
mongoose.connection
  .once('open', function () {
    console.log('MongoDB running');
  })
  .on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```